# How does the mode 'same' in np.correlate() work?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand the mode "same" in the function np.correlate(). I saw the definition in some website, but I can't understand how it does the computation to get the final array.

How from this: `np.correlate([2, 1], [1, 1], 'same')` we get this: `array([2, 3])`

Can someone make a computation example?

Answer (score 6):

The `mode='same'` just implies that you will have a result equal to the size of the largest input array. It is a subset of the full cross correlation (there is a `mode='full'` option as well). In your example, we have:

```
  2 1 
1 1
------
0+2+0 = 2
```

(dot product, zero fill where appropriate, then "slide")

```
  2 1
  1 1
-----
  2+1 = 3
```

Hence the answer of `[2,3]`.

The full cross correlation would continue sliding.

```
  2 1
    1 1
-------
  0+1+0 = 1
```

So, the full cross correlation would be `[2,3,1]`.

Note: These keywords are derived from the MATLAB implementations of these functions

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the numpy manual，https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html，

Here is the example of numpy.convolve from the manual (the "mode" in numpy.correlate is the same as numpy.convolve)：

>>>np.convolve([1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0.5])

array([ 0. ,  1. ,  2.5,  4. ,  1.5])

#**Only return the middle values of the convolution. Contains boundary effects, where zeros are taken into account:**

>>>np.convolve([1,2,3],[0,1,0.5], 'same')

array([ 1. ,  2.5,  4. ])

#The two arrays are of the same length, so there is only one position where they completely overlap:

>>>np.convolve([1,2,3],[0,1,0.5], 'valid')

array([ 2.5])